# External CSS not working

Tags: html, css, external, internal

I need help again. I'm watching some tutorials, and I have an easy code that works fine with internal CSS, but I doesn't with external CSS. I think I'm doing everything right, since I don't change a single word of the code, excep for the external css reference. Any ideas why is it not working? Thanks for your answers! (By the way, I read all the post relationed with my problem, but nothing work out.) Here's the code:

```css
div.box
{
width:320px;
padding:10px;
border:10px solid green;
margin:0px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: large;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="new 1.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="box">This text in a box example uses css.<br /><b>Note:</b> there is a
DOCTYPE declaration (above the html element), so it displays correctly in all browsers.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It work out here! It is driving me insane. I tried it in Notepepad++, Brackets, and text editors. I really can't figure out what's happening.

Comment: is the file name "new 1.css", there is a space check it once.

Comment: There shouldn't be spaces in the URL, use `href="new%201.css"`.

Comment: I forget to say that the files are in the same folder, and I tried too with subfolders.

Comment: My best guess: spaces in URLs don't work in your web server or browser; the CSS is somewhere else; it loads properly but it has nothing to offer; perhaps it's somewhere the server wasn't configured to serve from?

Comment: Guffa, that doesn't work, i'm gonna try change the name of both files without spaces to see what happens.

Comment: It works changing the name of the files without spaces, thanks to all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have spaces in a URL, try changing the space to its ASCII character: `%20` so it would look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="new%201.css">
```

Or what I would normally do is use proper file naming conventions, either camel case (every word [ besides the first one] starts with an upper case letter) or use underscores between the names.

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem a few days ago. (And I had no spaces in my file name..)

As soon as I outsourced my CSS code in an external file, the exact same problem came across.

For me the problem was in the encoding.

For those who have this problem too: Just **switch the file encoding to UTF-8** . (I used Notepad++)

Maybe you have to add to your html file:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

And then it should finally work.

see more here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp

Answer (score 2):

Change encoding of the css file to utf-8 using simple notepad.
Open css file by notepad, save as then choose utf-8 from encoding tab then save.

Comment: Wow! That's great this saved my time

Answer (score 0):

Remember to check that there is no  inline style.
So, an inline style has the highest priority, and will override external and internal styles and browser defaults.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. But I understood that my wrong is here: when I was writing HTML file, I changed the direction of this file to a folder and created a CSS file next to it.
So my path for CSS file became wrong. Now I recommend to first close your editor of HTML or CSS, after choosing your direction of these files, then open your editor and write your code.